# Are there any worthwhile benefits to saving Cid in the World of Ruin?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I've been reading that it is possible to keep Cid alive after Celes wakes up from you coma on Solitary Island in *Final Fantasy VI*, from what I've read if I end up saving Cid, instead of Celes finding out about the raft from Cid's note he shows it to her himself

Considering that there are only 2 good fish that will raise Cid's health, his health drops by 1 every second your not in a menu, you can let it drop bellow 30 and have to raise it above 255 to save him it seems like a hell lot of work and I've always thought that after Cid's death and Celes's attempted suicide due to her now being left alone in the world made for a better motivation for her to search for Locke after seeing that bird.

So i'm wondering, apart from the slight change in how he finds the raft to leave the island, is there any worth while changes what would validate spending so much time trying to save Cid cause i remember spending 10 minutes getting fish repeatedly to get nowhere so I just then waited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already succeed when I was young to let him live by feeding him only fast fish. I far as I can remember, NO. There's no benefit for the hard work that you made... Only self accomplishment.